# Vi regular expression

Tags: regex, vi

Looking to perform a find and replace on the following string:

```
"_id" : { "$oid" : "52853800bb1177ca391c17ff" }, "Ticker" : "A", "Profit Margin" : 0.137,    "Institutional Ownership" : 0.847, "EPS growth past 5 years" : 0.158, "Total Debt/Equity" : 0.5600000000000001, "CurrentRatio" : 3, "Return on Assets" : 0.089, "Sector" : "Healthcare", "P/S" : 2.54, "Change from Open" : -0.0148, "Performance (YTD)" : 0.2605, "Performance (Week)" : 0.0031, "Quick Ratio" : 2.3, "Insider Transactions" : -0.1352, "P/B" : 3.63, "EPS growth quarter over quarter" : -0.29, "Payout Ratio" : 0.162, "Performance (Quarter)" : 0.09279999999999999, "Forward P/E" : 16.11, "P/E" : 19.1, "200-Day Simple Moving Average" : 0.1062, "Shares Outstanding" : 339, "Earnings Date" : { "$date" : 1384464600000 }, "52-Week High" : -0.0544, "P/Cash" : 7.45, "Change" : -0.0148, "Analyst Recom" : 1.6, "Volatility (Week)" : 0.0177, "Country" : "USA", "Return on Equity" : 0.182, "50-Day Low" : 0.0728, "Price" : 50.44, "50-Day High" : -0.0544, "Return on Investment" : 0.163, "Shares Float" : 330.21, "Dividend Yield" : 0.0094, "EPS growth test years" : 0.13 }
```

Specifically, I want to find all characters in quotations and remove any whitespaces found.  i.e. "Profit Margin" becomes "ProfitMargin", "Institutional Ownership" becomes "InstitutionalOwnership" etc.   I'd like to do this in Vi.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What does your current regex look like, and what specific problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer:

```
:%s/\("[^"]*"\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), " ", "", "g")/g
```

And the way I got it:

1. Search what we want to replace => `/".*"` (quote symbol + n times whatever + quote symbol)
2. Do it properly => `/"[^"]*"` (quote symbol + n times whatever is not a quote symbol + quote symbol)
3. Transform that into a substitution that does nothing => `:%s/\("[^"]*"\)/\1/g`
4. Check `:help :%s`, from there `:help sub-replace-special`.
5. Use the magic `\=` learned before, still doing nothing => `:%s/\("[^"]*"\)/\=submatch(1)/g`
6. Replace `\=submatch(1)` by something useful => `:%s/\("[^"]*"\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), " ", "", "g")/g` (`:help substitute`).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Worked perfectly!